# ¿Como puedo unir estas dos consultas?

Tags: sql

```
select Nombre, sum(Compras_Productos.Cantidad) as Cant_adq
from Compras_Productos, Productos
where Compras_Productos.Id_Producto=Productos.Codigo
order by Nombre

select Nombre, sum(Ventas_Productos.Cantidad) as Cant_vendida
from Ventas_Productos, Productos
where Ventas_Productos.Id_Producto=Productos.Codigo
order by Nombre
```

[image: Este es el resultado que me debería de dar]

Comment: añade por favor que gestor de bases de datos usas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

considero que es asi:

```
SELECT p.Nombre,SUM(vp.Cantidad) as vendidos,SUM(cp.Cantidad) as adquiridos 
FROM Productos p 
LEFT JOIN Compras_Productos cp ON cp.Id_Producto = p.Codigo 
LEFT JOIN Ventas_Productos vp ON vp.Id_Producto = p.Codigo 
GROUP BY p.Nombre // este group solo por si acaso.
ORDER BY p.Nombre;
```

Saludos y buena energia :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo hice de esta manera, desconozco si exista otra manera mas sencilla de hacerlo.

```
SELECT P.Nombre AS Producto, SUM(CP.Cantidad) AS Cantidad INTO #Adquiridos 
FROM Compras_Productos CP INNER JOIN Productos P ON 
CP.Id_Producto=P.Codigo GROUP BY (P.Nombre) ORDER BY Nombre ASC;
SELECT P.Nombre AS Producto, SUM(Cantidad) AS Cantidad INTO #Vendidos FROM 
Ventas_Productos VP, Productos P WHERE VP.Id_Producto=P.Codigo GROUP BY 
(P.Nombre) ORDER BY P.Nombre ASC;
SELECT A.Producto AS Producto, SUM(A.Cantidad) AS Cant_Adquirida, 
SUM(V.Cantidad) AS Cant_Vendida INTO #AdquiVend FROM #Adquiridos A LEFT 
JOIN #Vendidos V ON A.Producto=V.Producto GROUP BY (A.Producto);
UPDATE #AdquiVend SET Cant_Vendida=0 WHERE Cant_Vendida IS NULL;
SELECT Producto, Cant_Adquirida, Cant_Vendida, Cant_Adquirida-Cant_Vendida 
AS Saldo INTO #Saldo FROM #AdquiVend;
SELECT *FROM #Saldo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la instrucción UNION, de la siguiente manera:

```
select Nombre, sum(Compras_Productos.Cantidad) as Cant_adq
from Compras_Productos, Productos
where Compras_Productos.Id_Producto=Productos.Codigo
order by Nombre
UNION
select Nombre, sum(Ventas_Productos.Cantidad) as Cant_vendida
from Ventas_Productos, Productos
where Ventas_Productos.Id_Producto=Productos.Codigo
order by Nombre
```

Answer (score 1):

podes intentar igualando las claves para las tres tablas, y el GROUP BY para que las cantidades vayan de acuerdo al nombre del producto:

```
select      Nombre, sum(compras_productos.cantidad) as Cant_Adquirida, sum(ventas_productos.cantidad) as Cant_Vendida, sum(compras_productos.cantidad) - sum(ventas_productos.cantidad) as Saldo
from        compras_productos, productos, ventas_productos
where       compras_productos.id_producto = productos.codigo and productos.codigo = ventas_productos.id_producto
group by    Nombre
order by    Nombre
```